# Codeigniter: getting the value of the textbox

Tags: php, codeigniter

please help me. is it possible to get the value of a textbox without submitting? and then i will use it in a query. it is something like this

> Select * from my_table where id = ($data);

i tried `$data['example'] = $this->input-post('name_of_textbox');` but it is not working. i think that code needs to be submitted for it to get the value.

i will not put the value in my table/database. i will use it for a variable for my query.

please help me. thank you very much.

Comment: Without submitting? What you need is called *ajax*.

Comment: can you please give me some reliable links of tutorial of ajax? can you please give me a sample?

Comment: [Reference 1](https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/334396/get-the-value-of-a-textbox-on-onchange) , [autocomplete tutorial](http://tutsforweb.blogspot.in/2012/05/auto-complete-text-box-with-php-jquery.html)

Comment: $data['example'] = $this->input->post('name_of_textbox');

Answer (score 0):

below is simple ajax call to submit data...

```
<input type='text' name='link_text' id='link_text' value='' class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter Link...">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary btn-sm" id="add_menu_submit" action="save" title="Save Menu">Add</button>

$(document).off("click", "#add_menu_submit").on('click', "#add_menu_submit", function () {
        var ele = $(this);
        ajax_call({
            url: site_url('menu/menu_insert'),
            data: $("#add_menu_form").serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            success: function (result) {

            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your textbox is in a form, then of course you have to submit form to get its value by

```
$this->input->post('name_of_textbox');
```

if you don't want to submit form use javascript.
Find the value of textbox run php code via ajax request in any javascript event as per your requirement.